# casting column datatype into numeric using SQL AWS Athena

Tags: python, sql, amazon-athena

I am trying to cast the amount column as numeric as per the following SQL query using Athena AWS.

```
round(cast(amount as numeric),3)
```

But the numeric data type is not recognized and it pops out the following error

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 19:54: Unknown type: numeric unable to rollback

Comment: Athena doesn't have numeric data type as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html. Can you confirm what is the value type in source and to what type you want to cast it to with examples?

Comment: Try something like `CAST(amount AS decimal(16, 3))`